# how to draw smooth lines on canvas without clearing it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas that is adding dynamically to the page on on load.
I want to draw user's mouse path on the canvas, but I found that if I clear the canvas before drawing, it will draw smooth lines, otherwise, it will draw ugly lines like following screenshot!
[image]

To test the problem, please uncomment first line of `draw_on_canvas` function in the code to see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Create DRAWING environment
  var canvasWidth = 400;
  var canvasHeight = 200;
  var drawn_shape_list = [];
  var current_shape_info = {};
  var is_painting = false;

  function add_path_to_drawn_shape_list() {
    if (current_shape_info.path && current_shape_info.path.length > 0) {
      drawn_shape_list.push(current_shape_info);
    }

    current_shape_info = {};
  }

  function add_path(x, y) {
    current_shape_info.color = "#000000";
    current_shape_info.size = 2;

    if (!current_shape_info.path) {
      current_shape_info.path = [];
    }

    current_shape_info.path.push({
      "x": x,
      "y": y
    });
  }

  function draw_on_canvas() {
    //Uncomment following line to have smooth drawing!
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); //clear canvas
    context.strokeStyle = current_shape_info.color;
    context.lineWidth = current_shape_info.size;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(current_shape_info.path[0].x, current_shape_info.path[0].y);

    for (var i = 1; i < current_shape_info.path.length; i++) {
      context.lineTo(current_shape_info.path[i].x, current_shape_info.path[i].y);
    }
    context.stroke();
  }

  //Create canvas node
  var canvas_holder = document.getElementById('canvas_holder');
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
  canvas.setAttribute('id', 'whitboard_canvas');
  canvas_holder.appendChild(canvas);
  if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
  }
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  $('#canvas_holder').mousedown(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    is_painting = true;
    add_path(mouseX, mouseY, false);
    draw_on_canvas();
  });

  $('#canvas_holder').mousemove(function(e) {
    if (is_painting) {
      var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

      var can = $('#whitboard_canvas');
      add_path(mouseX, mouseY, true);
      draw_on_canvas();
    }
  });

  $('#canvas_holder').mouseup(function(e) {
    is_painting = false;
    add_path_to_drawn_shape_list();
  });

  $('#canvas_holder').mouseleave(function(e) {
    is_painting = false;
    add_path_to_drawn_shape_list();
  });
});
```

```css
#canvas_holder {
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

canvas {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="canvas_holder"></div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

You can see an example of my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dnm2ys5j/) with two canvas.

I have tried `context.lineJoin = "round";` and  `context.lineCap = 'round';`, but the result didn't change.

Is it normal canvas behavior or I should set something?

Comment: `BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur();` is not valid JavaScript, also `BoxBlur` is not defined anywhere

Comment: oh sorry it was a mistake from my last test. I will remove it now

Comment: It’s normal for the canvas not to clear itself, yes. You’re seeing the effect of the path being redrawn on top of the last draw. Is there a reason you don’t want to clear it?

Comment: @Ry- just because of performance. it is going to be a whiteboard, if I redraw every time, I need to draw everything from the beginning. isn't it resource consumer?

Comment: `I need to draw everything from the beginning` Your doing that anyway..

Comment: Oh, it should be simpler now that there’s no blur step. You can just draw the latest line instead of all the lines.

Comment: @Keith assume there is 100 drawing path that drawn right now on the canvas. for 101th, I don't need to redraw all last 100 paths. right now, I will draw each path individually and I am not clearing all recently drawn paths.

Comment: I have added an update link: https://jsfiddle.net/dnm2ys5j/

Comment: @RezaAmya That's not what I'm on about, your currently drawing all points again, not clearing the canvas doesn't effect that.  And is the reason for the none smooth appearance, as Alpha black on top of Alpha black, in the end creates black.  Also -> `for (var i = 1;`  might also be worth pointing out arrays are zero based.  Like @Ry pointed out just draw the latest lines only.

Answer (score 1):

> how to draw smooth lines on canvas without clearing it?

You don't. Clearing and redrawing is the way to go.

> Is it normal canvas behavior

Yes completely. Unless you perform some action that should clear the canvas, it won't be cleared. So when you draw multiple times over the same area using semi transparent color, the pixels will become darker and darker.

Don't be afraid of performances, having to deal with the compositing of previous drawings may even be slower than drawing a single more complex path.

One thing you can do to improve performances is to use a single Path, so that at every frame only a single paint operation occurs:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const path = new Path2D();
const mouse = {};

function draw() {
  // clear all
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  // draw the single path
  ctx.stroke( path );
  // tell we need to redraw next frame
  mouse.dirty = false;
}

canvas.onmousedown = (evt) => {
  mouse.down = true;
  // always use the same path
  path.moveTo( evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY );
};
document.onmouseup = (evt) => {
  mouse.down = false;
};
document.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  if( mouse.down ) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    path.lineTo( evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top );
  }
  if( !mouse.dirty ) {
    mouse.dirty = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

If you need to have different path styles, then you can create one path per style.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const makePath = (color) => ({
  color,
  path2d: new Path2D()
});
const pathes = [makePath('black')];

const mouse = {};

function draw() {
  // clear all
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  pathes.forEach( (path) => {
    // draw the single path
    ctx.strokeStyle = path.color;
    ctx.stroke( path.path2d );
  } );
  // tell we need to redraw next frame
  mouse.dirty = false;
}

document.getElementById('inp').onchange = (evt) =>
  pathes.push( makePath( evt.target.value ) );

canvas.onmousedown = (evt) => {
  mouse.down = true;
  const path = pathes[ pathes.length - 1 ].path2d;
  // always use the same path
  path.moveTo( evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY );
};
document.onmouseup = (evt) => {
  mouse.down = false;
};
document.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  if( mouse.down ) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const path = pathes[ pathes.length - 1 ].path2d;
    path.lineTo( evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top );
  }
  if( !mouse.dirty ) {
    mouse.dirty = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<input type="color" id="inp"><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your solution about using one path was really interesting, but I think there is not such a big performance different between painting several path instead of painting one path with several point!
Also, I am searching for the answer of my question. performance is important, but it is not point of this question currently

Comment: @Reza yes there is a huge perfromance difference. You may not notice it with your small drawing pad, but when you'll come to draw tens of thousands objects per frame you'll understand. And I did answer the title of your question: "You don't". But I added a point about the one in the body.